# divs are fading in, but suddenly fades out (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-grid

i'm making a portfolio, and whenever i click the link, the right divs fade in/out, but then everything fades out.

what i'm trying to do is that there are multiple links, and whatever link i click, it hides the rest. couldnt figure out whats wrong.

```js
$('#about').on('click', function() {
 $('div').not('.about-content, .about-content2, .about-img').fadeOut(1000, 'swing', function(){
  $('.about-content').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
  $('.about-content2').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
  $('.about-img').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
 });
})
```

```css
/* content */
.about-content, .about-content2 {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="grid">
 <div class="nav-left">
  <a href="#" id="home">Name</a>
 </div>
 <div class="nav-right">
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
 </div>

 <!-- home -->
 <div class="home-content">
   <p>Web Developer</p>
 </div>

 <!-- about -->
 <div class="about-content">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <p>Lorem</p>
 </div>
 <div class="about-content2">
  <p>Ipsum</p>
  <div class="about-img">
  <img src="img/pic.jpg">
 </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is `$('div')`. With that you `fadeOut` the parent `.grid`. Try adding that to your `.not`.

Comment: You are fading out ALL divs without `.about-content, .about-content2, .about-img` => also the `div` containing everything `grid`

Comment: thanks! although one more problem, the divs are fading in while the divs are still fading out - found the solution to that .promise().done(function()

Answer (score 0):

Check you're code behavior:

```
$('#about').on('click', function() {
    $('div').not('.about-content, .about-content2, .about-img').fadeOut(1000, 'swing', function(){
        $('.about-content').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
        $('.about-content2').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
        $('.about-img').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
    });
})
```

If you're doing a fadeOut and then a function to fadeIn it's normal that you have both behaviors, clean it:

```
$('#about').on('click', function() {
    $('div').not('.about-content, .about-content2, .about-img', function(){
        $('.about-content').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
        $('.about-content2').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
        $('.about-img').fadeIn(1000, 'swing');
});
```

})